# Do we have any open source IDE to debugl source code of DXL

Tags: ibm-doors

**I like to know is there any Open source IDE to debug the source code of DXL.**

Answer (score 2):

Opensource, no. Are there solutions out there? Yes. Sodius is the first one that pops into my mind.

http://sodius.com/products-overview/dxl-editor